# Duplicate case error during switch case with and(&) operator

Tags: android, c++, touch

```
switch (v.getId() & event.getAction()) {
    case R.id.report_stype & MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        spinnertype();

        break;
    case R.id.report_sapprove & MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        break;

    }
```

both cases shows duplicate error..how to fix?

Comment: what is error ? Post your stacktrace. And you can not define the same Motion action two time.

Comment: showing error in eclipse editor ...but same motion with different views

Comment: Maybe you haven't correctly defined your 'and'(&&) operator? As you are using '&'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure you want to bitwise-and useing the & operator?

This does not guarantee two different values actually.

ACTION_DOWN for example may have those bits having value 1 that mask the ids in your both cases.

Try rethinking the logic.

You can do something like this:

```
switch (v.getId() ) {
case R.id.report_stype:
    if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
       spinnertype();

    break;
case R.id.report_sapprove:
    if( & event.getAction() ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        // do whatever

    break;

}
```

Hope this helps.